# Ring of invariants of a finite subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: invariant-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

In the paper:

Kac, Victor; Watanabe, Keiichi, *Finite linear groups whose ring of invariants is a complete intersection.* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 6 (1982), no. 2, 221–223

it is said in Remark 2 on page 222 that for any finite subgroup $G$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the ring of invariants $\mathbb{C}[X_1, X_2]^G$ is always a complete intersection ring without any reference.

Can anyone kindly tell me a reference for this result? Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Val_singularity

Comment: I am also considering finite subgroups of $GL_2\mathbb(C)$  which are not contained in $SL_2\mathbb(C)$

Comment: Here's a link to the paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-06-02/S0273-0979-1982-14989-8/ . The remark is wrong, almost certainly a typo.

Comment: For an explicit example, take $G$ to be the three-element group generated by $\mathrm{diag}(e^{2\pi i/3},e^{2\pi i/3})$.  The invariant ring is $\mathbb{C}[x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]$, which is not even Gorenstein.

Comment: Could you suggest some references to know more about the compete intersection property of ring of invariance?

Comment: As far as I know, the article of Kac and Watanabe is the state of the art. Just ignore this typo.  Or see this section of Neusel's book, and the references there: http://books.google.com/books?id=tLEyb4qhaRoC&pg=RA6-PA7&lpg=RA6-PA7&dq=finite+group+invariants+%22complete+intersection%22